# how to block time slots using php

Tags: php

i have two time fields like

```
if i  add new time i.e in b/w $a time and $b time, it is not suppose to take,
how to do this using php.
    if i  add new time i.e in b/w $a time and $b time, it is not suppose to take,
    how to do this using php.
    if i  add new time i.e in b/w $a time and $b time, it is not suppose to take,
```

if i  add new time i.e in b/w $a time and $b time, it is not suppose to take,
how to do this using php.
        how to do this using php.
        $a=10:00;
        $b=10:30;

```
    if i  add new time i.e in b/w $a time and $b time, it is not suppose to take,
    how to do this using php.

     <?php
    $c=$_POST['intime'];
    $d=$_POST['outtime'];

    if()
    {
    echo '';
    }

    else
    {
    insert query
    }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can use [date()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to get the current hour and minute then check if the value is in the range you want to block.

```
$nowInt = (int)date('Hi');
if($nowInt >= 1000 && $nowInt <= 1030) {
    echo 'request blocked';
} else {
    // do database insert
}
```

The `H` is 00 through 23 so it will match AM not PM. The `i` is 00 to 59. The date function produces a string but with the two numeric values concatinated you can simple cast it as an integer then do a straight numeric comparison.

With times before 10:00 AM, be careful with the leading zero since the cast to integer will remove them. So if you need to check for 9:00 AM the integer value will come out to 900.